# A simple string query which confuses me

Tags: java

I am new in Java and want to know the logic behind this question asked by a friend.

Say String pool is empty and

programmer execute

```
String str = new String("Raj");
```

How many objects will be created because of it.

My friend say there will be 3 objects created but does not know the logic behind it.

Could someone guide me how 3 objects will be created.

Comment: Basically your friend was wrong. But close to right.

Comment: If your friend was warning you about `String str = new String("Raj");` versus `String str = "Raj";`, they were right - just the literal is better to use.

Answer (score 5):

There are two String objects created, one is *String literal* "Raj", and one is an intermediate String object created by the `new String(...)`.

One can argue there is another (3rd) object, which is the `char[]` in the internals of the String literal, that you might also want to count, it is an object - but not a String object. (The new string will use the same `char[]`, and won't create a new one)

---

**EDIT**: Pointed out by @jdphenix, each created object is also a subclass of `Object`, and thus contain an instance of it, (you can cast it to Object and use it as such). So, technically, there are actually more than 3 objects created here - but only 2 of them are String objects.

Comment: If we really want to get pedantic, don't forget the `Object` superclass instance of the two `String` and `char[]` array.

Comment: @jdphenix It's the same object, it's the same instance.

Comment: I think then **StringBuilder** will also be created in string pool?

Comment: _The new string will use the same char[], and won't create a new one_ Actually, it does. The `String` constructor creates a new `char[]` and _copies_ the content to it, it doesn't reuse the existing one.

Comment: @BackSlash It reuses the same `char[]`. I am not sure if it is optimization or specified by the language though. I tested it, here is the code:   String s1 = "Raj";
  String s2 = new String(s1);
  Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
  f.setAccessible(true);
  System.out.println(f.get(s1) == f.get(s2));

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I was looking at the Java 6 source. Java 7 has a different implementation.

Comment: @amit Now I _have_ to figure out where I got the idea that each instance of any object that subclasses something has an instance of it's superclass built-in.

Comment: @jdphenix I misunderstood your comment, you meant in the memory layout. sorry. I believe you are correct here, I'll add an indication to that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, there will be two objects created.

```
"Raj"
```

and

```
new String("Raj");
```

Your friend is either incorrect or is... *stringing* you along.

I'm sorry.

**Edit**: As correctly pointed out, a third object is created, which is the `char[]` object in the internal of the `String`.

Comment: There are 2 String objects, but there's also a `char[]` in the internals of the String..

Answer (score 1):

2 objects will be created (a String literal `"Raj"` and a `String` object: `new String("Raj")`)
but only one `String` will be *interned* and put into the `String`'s internal pool (the String literal).

Answer (score 1):

Now I am confused..as fas as I know...intern() is the method which creates a string literal in String pool. that in this case

String str = new String("Raj");

str.intern(); // this will put the Raj in string pool; or my understanding is incorrect.Each time i create a String object a string literal will be created in String pool if it is already not there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when that code executes, the pool will already have been filled, so your assumption that "the string pool will be empty" is not the case.

One string object will be in the pool for the string constant "Raj".
One string object will be created by the construction.

That's only 2 objects in all, and only 1 object crated as a result of that code being e excited.